# Symfony : Attempted to load class

Tags: classnotfoundexception, symfony, fpdi

I have install setasign/fpdi on my Symfony, I create a class for generate a PDF :

```
class MerchPDF extends \FPDI {.... }
```

and I have this error :

> Attempted to load class "FPDI" from the global namespace.
>   Did you forget a "use" statement?

on local, no problem.
on production, there is this error ... and all files are equals.

Are you an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Its in the fpdi_bridge that the error occurs. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you require `setasign/fpdi` as a composer dependency, the base `Fpdi` class is not available in the global namespace, but in `setasign\Fpdi` namespace. So your class should start like this:

```
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

class MerchPDF extends Fpdi {
    ...
}
```

Not sure why it works locally, probably you have installed `Fpdi` by other means (i.e. not via composer) so it's available as a class in the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

please have you already try  to remove both TCPDF (if it is installed too) and FPDI from the classmap of the composer.json. Then  add both: "tecnick.com/tcpdf": "dev-master", "setasign/fpdi": "1.4.2(here the version)", To the "require" part of the composer.json ?